# Function of a sufficient statistic

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, estimation, nonparametric, sufficient-statistics

It is well-known that a 1-1 function of a sufficient statistic is also sufficient for a parameter $p$.

I am however confused by the consequence that if $T$ is sufficient for a parameter $p$, then a one-to-one function $f(T)$ is sufficient for $p$ or is it for $f(p)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sufficiency is not linked to the parameterisation of the model or of the observations, so

1. conditioning on a random variable $Z$ is identical to conditioning on any bijective and measurable transform $\Psi$ of $Z$, $Y=\Psi(Z)$;
2. the distribution of $X$ given $Z=S(X)$ being constant in the parameter $p$ means it is also constant in any bijective transform of the parameter $p$

Answer (score 2):

I would say both since $F_p(x)=F_{f^{-1}(f(p))}(x)$, so that if $P(X\in A |f(T),p)=P(X\in A|T,p)=P(\in A|T)=P(X\in A|f(T))$, since $f(T)=c\Leftrightarrow T=f^{-1}(c)$.

Answer (score 0):

Both are, if the functions are **bijective**, i.e. one-to-one and correspondence. You can look at it as if you can inverse each one of the functions (due to their one-to-one property) in its turn, in order to perform estimation.

Comment: Oh... sorry about that, I didn't notice the edit. I've edited mine as well - added the bijection requirement and took out the comment on constant functions.