# When a function of sufficient statistic is itself sufficient?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, sufficient-statistics, function, factorisation-theorem

I'm following notes at [onlinecourses](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/283/) and I got confused on transformation of sufficient statistics. For example, if $X$ is a sufficient statistic for $\mu$, why $Y=X^2$ is not a sufficient statistic for $\mu$? In another source [Essentials of Statistical Inference](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Essentials-Statistical-Inference-Probabilistic-Mathematics/dp/0521548667) by G. A. Young p. 92 $|X|$ is sufficient. Aren't both $X^2$ and $|X|$ many-to-one functions? Why in Young's book the sign no longer matters? Is this something to do with having single observation? Apologies in advance if this question was already asked.

Extract from [onlinecourses](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/283/):
[image]

Later in the text the following is mentioned:
[image]

Here is an extract from Young's book:

[image]

Comment: Sufficiency depends on the context. From what distribution are the data sampled? What parameter is being estimated? First step is to check whether the context the exactly same in the online course notes as in Young's book.

Comment: @BruceET Context is slightly different in that in Young's book the variance is unknown but mean is known. Another difference that I suspect is more important is that in Young's book there is a single observation, whereas online course involves a sample of size $n>1$.

Comment: The important thing is that in Young's book we know $\mu = 0$ and are estimating $\sigma.$ So you are looking for a statistic that is "sufficient for (estimating) $\sigma$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on context. If $X$ (possibly a vector) is an observation from some statistical model, and $T=T(X)$ is sufficient, then any one-to-one function of $T$ is also sufficient,  see [Function of a sufficient statistic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339286/function-of-a-sufficient-statistic).  But in some cases a function of $T$ which is not one-to-one *might* also be sufficient. In such cases $T$ will not be minimal sufficient. So on to your examples:

- Say $X=(X_1, \dotsc, X_n)$ is a sample from the model $\mathcal{Norm}(\mu, 1)$. Then $T=\bar{X}_n$ is sufficient, and so is any one-to-one function of $T$, like $T^{1/3}$. But the square is not one-to-one, so say if $T=1000$, then if you report only $T^2=1000000$, you loose the information about the sign, so cannot discriminate between the models $\mu=1000$ and $\mu=-1000$. On the basis of $T=1000$ you *can* discriminate those models. That should explain why $T^2$ *in this model* is not sufficient.
- The other example, the model $\mathcal{Norm}(0, \sigma^2)$. This model is a *symmetric distribution*, and observing $T=1000$ or observing $T=-1000$ gives the same information about the variance $\sigma^2$. So in this case $\vert T \vert$ or $T^2$ are still sufficient.